# How to make a DOM element update after an object it depends on changes in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an object in an array

```
var 
sidelist = [
    {
    name:"MURICA", 
    types:[...]
    }
];
```

I have a box that displays the object's name. Then I have a text field and a button. On button press the object's name gets set to text field value. But I don't know how to make the name in the box change accordingly.

As I understand putting the object in a session variable is not an option since I will not be able to modify properties of objects inside of it without resetting the whole session var. I tried it and failed.

Comment: Have you **at least** done the first exercise recommended on Meteor page? See here: http://meteor.com/examples/leaderboard . Your question is ultra-basic!

Comment: Hubert OG, you may be too harsh with Euphe here and your answer a bit too simplistic. I believe (Euphe, please correct me if I am wrong) that the case is that the data is in an ARRAY and not in a Meteor Collection as you seem to assume. The problem is that Collections are reactive data sources in Meteor while arrays of course are not. In other words Meteor will track all changes that occur in a Collection and automagically update the template that uses that Collection. However, this is not true for data in an array. I hope this clarifies things a bit. Euphe, please confirm this is the case.

Comment: @babbata is completely right. The problem is that I can actually put an object (array) into a Session which is a reactive data source. But then I can't edit it's properties, which I need to do alot. If it was that simple...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to offend anyone. I just remember having very similar problems after reading what Meteor is about, but before doing any code. But with your comments, I think I misunderstood the question. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**html**

```
<template name="asdf">
    {{#with object}}
        <div>{{name}}</div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

**js**

```
Template.asdf.object = function() {
    return Objects.findOne(...);
};
```

---

**EDIT**

I think I've got your question wrong, sorry. If you have a value in **memory** that you'd like to change and have the DOM updated, use dependencies:

**html**

```
<template name="asdf">
    {{property}}
</template>
```

**js**

```
var property;
// Create new dependency object that will manage refreshing property value:
var _dep = new Deps.Dependency;


updateProperty = function(value) {
    property = value;
    // Whenever you change value of the property, call changed() function:
    _dep.changed();
};

Template.asdf.value = function() {
    // Within reactive function, call depend() to rerun the function
    // each time the value is changed:
    _dep.depend();
    return value;
};
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the #with handler?

Comment: `#with` handlers adds the properties of given object into the namespace, so that they can be accessed directly. These are equivalent: `{{#with object}}{{property}}{{/with}}`, `{{object.property}}`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I need.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Probably because I can't get into understanding how it works to make it work for my full code.

Comment: Can you describe what problems do you have?

Comment: I have an array of objects that turns into a row of boxes on the page via templates and a panel that adds a new object to it. Since my template uses an {{#each}} construction it should create a box based on that new object. The object is added, but the page doesn't update

Comment: Ok, so use `depend()` in the template function that returns the array for `{{#each}}` construct, and `changed()` every time **after** you add a new object to the array. Does it help?

Comment: Maybe I should create a new question?

Comment: Perhaps. And be a bit more elaborate :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a different and in my opinion simpler solution - using a local collection for your data.

I am not sure exactly why do you keep that sort of data into an array, but if it is because you only need it on the client then you can instead create a local collection and have all the reactivity benefits without writing all that code for making the array reactive. The data stored in a local collection is never sent to the server, so no communication or storage overhead.

You'd do it like that:

```
Sidelist = new Meteor.Collection(null);
```

[EDIT] Put the above line in your client-side-only part of the code.

Notice the null parameter. This will give you a collection that is only stored on the client and is a regular Meteor reactive source. Then you go about using it in your code and html just as you would a normal collection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But then, wouldn't accessing data inside be hard?